# Compare similarities in a list using hashes?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Say you have a list:

```
L1 = [milk, butter, bread, shampoo, dog food]
```

and you want to know how similar this list is to another list

```
L2 = [milk, butter, shampoo, dog food, coffee]
```

That is get the union of two lists:

```
Result = L1 U L2
```

and Result is

```
[Milk, butter, dog food]
```

Now, I know I can iterate over these and find the union. But given a list of size m and a list of size n. You will iterate this at least min(n, m) times. Given x lists, you have x^min(n,m) iterations which can get pricy.

I was thinking hashes could be the way, but I am not sure.

But if there was a way to minimize a list down to one string and compare it to another string.

that is H(L1) U H(L2) has x% in common?

Note that I don't actually need to know what were the items in common. Just that they have a percentage shared between the two.

Comment: Have you checked on the `set` builtin?  It's probably the data type for what you're after.

Comment: You say Union, but your result is the intersection

Comment: What does this have to do with cryptography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have duplicates in the two lists, you could use sets instead, which do use hashes internally -

```
>>> L1 = {'milk', 'butter', 'bread', 'shampoo', 'dog food'}
>>> L2 = {'milk', 'butter', 'shampoo', 'dog food', 'coffee'}
>>> L1 & L2
{'dog food', 'butter', 'shampoo', 'milk'}
```

If you *do* need to handle duplicates, Python has a multiset in the form of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and its intersection operation does what you would expect:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(L1) & Counter(L2)
Counter({'butter': 1, 'milk': 1, 'shampoo': 1, 'dog food': 1})
```

To get the 'x% in common' string, you would need to compare the total number of elements in the intersection to the number of elements you started with. Sets support `len()` in the same way lists do, so getting the number of items in common if you don't have duplicates is just `len(L1 & L2)`. Taking the length of a Counter will only give you the number of *distinct* elements - to get the number of elements counted up to their multiplicity when L1 and L2 are Counters, you could do:

```
 common = L1 & L2
 num_in_common = sum(common.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how sets work. Convert the lists to sets and you can take the union/intersection

```
S1 = set(L1)
S2 = set(L2)
result = S1.intersection(S2)
```

This won't preserve the order though.